# How can I send variable using href tag along with URL in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

```
for (var i in result) 
{
 $('#tgt').append( "<li><a href='/UpdateStatusData/?id='"+result[i]+" >"+result[i]+"</a></li>");            
}
```

I am receiving blank in the id when extracting in server side. Please help me with the valid way of passing value to the tag.[but I am getting the value when i inspect the element along with ="" as extra, you can see it in the image value:MULTINOMIAL, but when I click I could only see blank value in the server side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUySA.png)

Comment: @Satpal thank you so much that worked for me!! :) +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of now the generated link would be below hence, id is ignored.

```
<a href'/UpdateStatusData/?id=' 123>
```

Place quotes properly so that the url is enclosed in quotes.

```
"<li><a href='/UpdateStatusData/?id="+result[i]+"'>"
                                  //^Removes 
                                               //^added
```

---

Use cleaner approach to create element using jQuery

```
var anchor = $('<a>', {
    href : '/UpdateStatusData/?id='+result[i]
});
var li = $('<li>');

li.append(anchor);
$('#tgt').append(li);
```